# How do I custom align my axis titles in Plotly Js i.e. right align the axis title?

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Plotly Js and would like to right align my x-axis title so that it sits underneath the right end of the x axis. I need my axis labels to also remain part of the SVG graph image that Plotly produces.

I have looked through the Plotly JS documentation and also searched various forums for a solution. the only item that Plotly seems to have related to axis title positioning is the `automargin` property, which does not allow me to specify where to position the title away from the centre of the x axis.

Does Plotly have a way to handle this? If not, are there any solutions to work around this?

[I want my sample x axis title right aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofDGf.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are any parameters that can be used to right align the x-axis title. One workaround would be to use an annotation, set the x and y coordinates to use paper coordinates, and then set `x=1` (right align) and `y=-0.25` to position the annotation text just below the x-axis. I have created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/merillium/pen/gOmpjdO).

Here is the code:

```
var data = [{
  type: 'bar',
  x: ['high pH stress 12 months', 'heat stress 24 months', 'heat stress 12 months'],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
}];

var layout = {
  annotations: [
    {
      xref: 'paper',
      yref: 'paper',
      x: 1,
      xanchor: 'right',
      y: -0.25,
      yanchor: 'bottom',
      text: 'Samples',
      font: {
          size: 16
        },
      showarrow: false
    }
  ]
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

[image]